# How to avoid negative numbers on axis in matplotlib scatterplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am doing a simple scatterplot using Pythons scatterplot. But no matter how I set my axis, and no matter that I don't have any negative values I get negative values at the x-axis. How do I force the axis to start at 0?

My code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.scatter(lengths,breadths, alpha=0.3, color="#e74c3c", edgecolors='none')
spines_to_remove = ['top', 'right']
for spine in spines_to_remove:
    ax.spines[spine].set_visible(False)
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
ax.xaxis.set_view_interval(0,400)
ax.yaxis.set_view_interval(0,90)
figname = 'scatterlengthsbreadths.pdf'
fig.savefig(figname, bbox_inches='tight')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`ax.set_xlim(lower_limit, upper_limit)`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim) to choose your x-limits. Note that there is a similar command `ax.set_ylim` for the y-limits.

Note that if you're just using the pyplot interface, i.e. without using `fig` and `ax`, then the command is `plt.xlim()`.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3]
y = [4,5,6]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x, y)

ax.set_xlim(0, 10)

plt.show()
```

[image]